# Understanding a Substep of the Proof for the Law of Total Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

In the proof for the [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance#Proof), the following lemma seems to be appealed to (when going from the 2nd to the 3rd step of the proof):

$$
E[E[Y^2 \mid X]] = E[\text{Var}[Y \mid X] + [E[Y \mid X]]^2]
$$

Where does this come from and/or what justifies it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expectation of

$$
E[Y^2\mid X]=\operatorname{Var}[Y\mid X]+E[Y\mid X]^2\;,
$$

which is the conditional version of the definition of the variance,

$$
E[Y^2]=\operatorname{Var}[Y]+E[Y]^2\;.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Discrete version:
$$
\text{Var}[Y|X]=\sum_{y}(y-E[Y|X])^2p_{Y|X}(y|x)\\=\sum_yy^2p_{Y|X}(y|x)-2E[Y|X]\sum_y yp_{Y|X}(y|x)+E[Y|X]^2\sum_{y}p_{Y|X}(y|x)\\
=E[Y^2|X]-2E[Y|X]^2+E[Y|X]^2=E[Y^2|X]-E[Y|X]^2\\
\therefore E[Y^2|X]=\text{Var}[Y|X]+E[Y|X]^2
$$