# Conditional variance definition

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

This question relates to this one:
[Understanding a Substep of the Proof for the Law of Total Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821396/understanding-a-substep-of-the-proof-for-the-law-of-total-variance)

It is written there, that we should be able to define conditional variance as $Var[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[X^2|\mathcal{F}]-(E[X|\mathcal{F}])^2$. But in order to pass to this definition from usual one, i.e. 
$$
Var[X|\mathcal{F}]=E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{F}])^2|\mathcal{F}]
$$
I need to know that 
$$
E[XE[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{F}]=(E[X|\mathcal{F}])^2.
$$
Seems plausible, but how I can see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(XY|\mathcal F)=YE(X|\mathcal F)$ whenever $Y$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F$ and $E|XY| <\infty$. [Here $X$ and $Y$ have finite second moments so $E|XY| \leq \sqrt {EX^{2}} \sqrt {EY^{2}} <\infty$]. Take $Y=E(X|\mathcal F)$ in this formula.

Comment: Shouldn't $Y$ be bounded?

Comment: It is enough if $E|XY| <\infty$. $X$ and $Y$ have finite second moments: $EY^{2} \leq EX^{2}$ by conditional Jensen's in equality.

Comment: Ok, I think I can see that - the proof should go by classic complication of variable, right? (Characteristic function of a set, then simple function, monotone convergence...). But why do we need the finiteness condition?

Comment: Is it because we need both variables to have expectation and variance?

Comment: In fact, suing your approach we can write down version of montone convergence theorem, convergence theorem etc for conditional expectations.

Comment: @IgorSikora $E(XY|\mathcal F$ is defined only when  $XY$ has finite expectation. This condition is satisfied whenever $X$ and $Y$ have finite variance.